# How to get image file format if it doesn't have an extension?

Tags: php

I have a folder of image files. Some of them don't have any extension. I need to find their format and attach proper extension to them through PHP or shell programming in Linux/Ubuntu. Can anyone please help me how to do it?

Comment: http://php.net/getimagesize

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I dont have enough reputation to post a comment, so...
See if this does anything

```
$finfo = finfo_open(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE);
$mime = finfo_file($finfo, $_FILES['afile']['tmp_name']);
```

this should store detected file format into $mime.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `getimagesize()` in conjunction with `image_type_to_extension` to get it:

```
$image_witout_a_file_extension = 'path/to/my/images_folder/image_name';
$info = getimagesize($image_witout_a_file_extension);
$extension = image_type_to_extension($info[2]);
echo $extension;
```